# Colab Pro+: Error "Cannot connect to GPU backend" for several days

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can not connect to a GPU on my Colab Pro+ for more than 5 days. I suppose this must be a bug.

I understand that GPUs are allocated dynamically, but if someone pays Pro+ it would be essential to get a smaller GPU at least. I can not even develop anything atm, because I can't run specific code without a GPU.

10 days of this month I was not using Colab (holidays), then some days of use and now 5 days with the error message "Cannot connect to GPU backend".

Trying to contact the support is a nightmare: I only get automated answers for 5 days in a row. It's an interesting platform but if there is a problem you are screwed and your 50$/month are just wasted.